# Mac Snow Leopard opening the same program in multiple Spaces

Tags: mac, osx-snow-leopard, osx-spaces

I noticed that if I had Safari open in say, Space 1, I would be sent back to Space 1 if I tried to open Safari in any other space.  Now I know that I can open multiple windows of Safari in Space 1 and then just move the windows manually, but is there an easy way to open an already opened program in a new Space?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The default Spaces behavior, when switching applications, is to switch back to a space if that space already has open windows for that application. This is basically what you've described: If you already have a Safari window open in Space 1, switching to Safari will move you back to Space 1.

To disable this behavior, go to System Preferences -> Exposé and Spaces, select the Spaces tab, and deselect "When switching to an application, switch to a space with open windows for the application".

Answer (score 2):

RIght-click on Safari in the Dock and select New Window.

Answer (score 0):

I just deselected this checkbox on system pref's and it still moves to a space with an open document.  For instance, I work with a lot of excel spreadsheets.  I will have several projects open in different spaces that consist of a browser, word document and a few spreadsheets.  When arranging a new space for another project, i will utilize spotlight to open the documents.  But, every time, it will jump to the nearest space with an open excel sheet before it opens the one found in spotlight.  I unchecked the box, and, no change.....  Hmmmm.