# what the uses of Spaces in MacOs?

Tags: macos, osx-spaces

hai

I'm using MacBook in my office. In MacOS Spaces is one utility to use i wonder that it nice to view multiple window. but if i click the mozilla or some browser in one view i can't open it separately in another view of spaces is there any option for that? give me the solution

Comment: Duplicate of [this thread](http://superuser.com/questions/33273/mac-snow-leopard-opening-the-same-program-in-multiple-spaces). You should use the search function before asking questions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand this right, you want to open windows of one application in multiple spaces. You can do that. Just uncheck the option `When switching to an application, switch to a space with open windows for the application` in `Expose & Spaces` preference pane in `System Preferences`.